# Binomial Theorem Derivative

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Derive the binomial theorem with respect to $x$ (then setting $x$ to an appropriate value) to evaluate the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot(-3)^k{n \choose k}$$ for $n > 0$. Write your function as a function of $n$.

So, I have taken the derivative of the binomial theorem of $(n)(1+x)^{n-1}$.

That derivative looks kinda similar to the sum, so I tried plugging in -4 for k to get the -3, but that leaves me with negative factorials.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please do not post homework exercises and give us orders to do your homework. You must make efforts and show us what you've done, what you know and ask a specific question.

Comment: I am sorry about that. Yes, I have tried to do the problem a bit but got stuck. I will go ahead and edit the post with my work.

Comment: I have just updated it. Sorry about that.

Comment: To get ${}^{n-1}$ write `^{n-1}`.

Answer (score 0):

Set $f_n(x) = (1-3x)^n.$ Expand $f_n$ using the binomial theorem. Then write $f_n'(x)$ in two ways: as the derivative of $(1-3x)^n$ and as the derivative of the expansion. Then set $x=1.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Differentiating the binomial formula, you obtain
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom nk x^{k-1},$$
which is almost your sum. What should you take for $x$?

Comment: Hmmm. Ok I do have a couple questions still because I want to try and understand this. It appears that I just need to plug in x = -4 to get something really close, but the k=0 part and k-1 part are just slightly different. 1) How did you get the right side of the equation? 2) Do these extra k = 0 and k - 1 parts matter? Or if we change it to k = 1, will the k = k -1 cancel down to just k?

Comment: 1) I wrote it: differentiating the binomial formula  (which I didn't care to rewrite). 2) the term with $k=0$ disappears (I wrote the raw formula – the sum really starts at $k=1$). As to the exponent $k-1$, which differs from yours, you just have to multiply both sides by $x$. Last point: no, you don't plug in $x=-4$.

Comment: Gotcha thanks. We never learned the condensed summation form of the formula which is why I was a bit confused (only the written out full form). I see now that I plug in -3 for x then multiply both sides by -3 to get the intended equation now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's exactly that.